# when to use require and when to use revert in solidity

Tags: solidity

Require and revert function does same task so when to use which function ? Which function uses less gas fees ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The benefit of using revert is that you can use custom errors

take a look at the following examples and results:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity 0.8.14;

error AmountShouldBeZero();

contract RequireVsRevert {
  function test(uint256 _amount) external pure {
    if (_amount != 0) revert AmountShouldBeZero();
  }
}
```

This costs **95649** gas to deploy in Remix

calling test with 1 as parameter, results in a gas cost of **21458** (with optimization = 200000)

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity 0.8.14;    

contract RequireVsRevert {
  function test(uint256 _amount) external pure {
    require(_amount == 0, "Amount should be zero");
  }
}
```

This costs **106755** gas to deploy in Remix

calling test with 1 as parameter, results in a gas cost of **21512** (with optimization = 200000)

as you can see using custom errors is more efficient in terms of gas consumption